# Google Analytics for subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, subdomain

I have two WordPress multisites under one domain - city-x.domain.com and city-y.domain.com. domain.com is a landing page where you select your city, and a cookie will redirect the user to that city on subsequent visits.

I'd like to be able to track the number of hits on all pages on domain.com, city-x.domain.com and city-y.domain.com separately and combined. How is this

On a side note, I've heard that GA underestimates hits. As this is important for advertising purposes, is there a better free service?

Answer (score 2):

I've configured separate profiles for each sub domains and main website, in Google Analytics.

1. Create an 'Account' first (say, citynewtwork)
2. Create 3 different 'Properties' under that account (say, website, cityx, cityy)
3. Create your 'Profiles' under each of the three properties

You'll get separate tracking code for each profiles...